# Find the maximum value of $y\cdot{x^2}+x$ if $y^2+x^2+x+y=100$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

We know that $y^2+x^2+x+y=100$. Find the maximum value of  $$y\cdot x^2+x$$ 
I tried to simplify it and use inequalities but I failed. Is there a way to solve it without calculus?

Comment: $y^2+x^2+x+y=100$ can be solved independently for x and y (gives roots in x : r(y) and roots in y r(x). Which gives you linear constraints to apply the Lagrangian method.

Answer (score 0):

You Can reduce your Problem in two variables in to one: from $$y^2+y-100+x^2+x=0$$ follows $$y=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+100-x^2-x}$$
so you will get
$$h(x)=\left(-1/2\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+100-x^2-x}\right)x^2+x$$

Comment: You beat me to this answer XD well done

Comment: How do you answer the question, i.e. find the maximum value of this without using calculus?

Comment: Your are wrong, the question was: Is there a way to solve this without calculus.

Comment: both the question title and the body of the question ask for the maximum value...

Comment: I don't know what is going on here!

Comment: Just read the question again!

Comment: This have i already done.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner you don't appear to have addressed the problem at all

Comment: @pranavB23 in what way does this actually answer the question?

Comment: @DavidQuinn one can use $h(x)$ to find the maximum value

Comment: @pranavB23 do you mean without using calculus?